# Does Postgresql 10 query partitions in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, postgresql-10

I'm curious if the new feature of Postgresql allows to take advantage of multiple cpus on server. In general there should be some worker that queries partitions and merges the results, and I expect it to be done in parallel. This becomes critical when foreign tables are used, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the closest answer for now:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/new-features-coming-postgresql-10
Improved Parallel Query.  While PostgreSQL 9.6 offers parallel query, this feature has been significantly improved in PostgreSQL 10, with new features like Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan, Parallel Index Scan, and others.  Speedups of 2-4x are common with parallel query, and these enhancements should allow those speedups to happen for a wider variety of queries.

Comment: Thanks, but I still see nothing about partitions

Answer (score 0):

No, partitions are not queried in parallel in Postgres 10.

That said, scan on an individual partition could still use multiple CPUs, but Postgres won't start scanning next partition until it has finished scanning the current one.  So, parallelism doesn't work *across* partitions yet, which is a feature that will most likely be available in the next major release (11).

Comment: Great! I've searched for this answer, could give some docs references about that?

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parallel-plans.html

Note that it doesn't mention the ability to execute Append itself in parallel.  Append is used to combine data from multiple partitions.